# editing sizes in plotly scatter

Tags: python, plotly, scatter

Here's a sample of my simple plotly chart:

```
px.scatter(data_frame=testdf,
       x = 'some_x',
       y = 'some_y',
       size = 'some_size',
       color = 'sth_colorful',
       title = 'stackoverflow',
       range_x = [-10, 1100],
       range_y = [-0.08, 1],
       hover_name = 'sth_i_want_to_check',
       animation_frame = 'year_of_course'
      )
```

It is alomost good. One thing that bothers me is that 'some_size' min value is about 20 and max is about 35 so it is hard to notice the size difference between the circles.
Is there a way I can manage the diameter of these? I'd like to keep the original values to appear in a hover.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the argument `size = 'some_size'` to `px.scatter`, this directly determines the size of the markers as they render on the plot.

However, what you can do to get around this is create a new column called `"display_size"` with your intended sizes for the markers, and set `customdata` to `df['some_size']` so you can access these values in the hovertemplate.

After that, you can loop through all of the traces in your `px.scatter` and modify the hovertemplate to display some_size instead of display_size.

For example:

```
## increase the standard deviation of the size values
## so that the difference between small and large markers is more apparent
testdf["display_size"] = 2*test_df["some_size"]

fig = px.scatter(data_frame=testdf,
       x = 'some_x',
       y = 'some_y',
       size = 'display_size',
       color = 'sth_colorful',
       title = 'stackoverflow',
       range_x = [-10, 1100],
       range_y = [-0.08, 1],
       hover_name = 'sth_i_want_to_check',
       animation_frame = 'year_of_course'
      )

fig.update_traces(customdata=testdf["some_size"])

## replace marker.size in the hovertemplate with your customdata (the actual size values)
for trace in fig.data:
    trace['hovertemplate'] = trace['hovertemplate'].replace('marker.size','customdata')
```